# Humming/Buzzing on OP-1 Synthesizer

Tags: synthesizer, equipment

Help! I just got my OP-1 and every time I start it up, it's fine but as soon as I push a note in synth mode it creates a background humming/buzzing and it doesn't stop.

Comment: Did you contact support about it? https://www.teenageengineering.com/contact

Comment: Related: when you get it working, check this out: https://youtu.be/TpIVf1dXrbU

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this only with the DNA Synth Engine and enabled effect. Other engines do work without this humming for me.

So switch off the effect or switching the synth engine should work.